# Detect if event listener is supported

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events, detection, browser-detection

Is it possible to detect if certain events are supported in certain browsers?
I can detect if the browser supports `document.addEventListener`, but I need to know if it supports the event `DOMAttrModified`. Firefox and Opera support it, but Chrome and others do not.

Comment: I don't think it's possible however look here to see support for IE and Chrome as well: http://help.dottoro.com/ljdchxcl.php

Comment: Thankyou, however I already have working solutions for all browsers. I was hoping for a way to detect if certain browsers supported the event so I can apply my alternative methods.

It seems I may have to resort to jQuery.browser detection.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Updated answer**:

**Yes**, you can feature-detect this. Create an element, listen for the event, and change an attribute on the element. In my tests, you don't even have to add the element to the DOM tree, making this a nice, contained feature detection.

Example:

```
function isDOMAttrModifiedSupported() {
    var p, flag;

    flag = false;
    p = document.createElement('p');
    if (p.addEventListener) {
        p.addEventListener('DOMAttrModified', callback, false);
    }
    else if (p.attachEvent) {
        p.attachEvent('onDOMAttrModified', callback);
    }
    else {
        // Assume not
        return false;
    }
    p.setAttribute('id', 'target');
    return flag;

    function callback() {
        flag = true;
    }
}
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/aqiwo3/6)

Firefox triggers the callback on all of the modifications above; Chrome on none of them.

---

**Original answer**:

You can feature-detect whether *some* events are supported, as shown on [this handy page](http://kangax.github.com/iseventsupported/). I don't know if you can test specifically for that one, but if you can, that code may well get you started.

**Update**: I [dumped Kangax's code into JSBin](http://jsbin.com/aqiwo3/3) and tried it, doesn't look like that sniffing technique works for that event (unless I have the name spelled incorrectly or something; Firefox is showing "false"). But my technique above does.

Comment: @ifaour: Wow, that **is** weird. Also FF 3.6. And yet, we all know that's not true...

Comment: ppk states [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/index.html#link2) that the `DOMAttrModified` type event doesn't work with the traditional `onEvent` event registration system, so that's probably what broke the test you have there, which only looks for the `onEvent` property in the element

Comment: @Yi Jiang: Yeah, kangax's code is for testing user-generated events. The test in my updated answer works great, since we can easily trigger the condition we're testing for. :-)

Comment: Thanks Crowder, works great! Coincidentally I actually just came up with this solution, and went to post it up here only to see you had beaten me to it!

Answer (score 0):

```
function isDOMAttrModifiedSupported () {
    var supported = false;
    function handler() {
      supported = true;
    }
    document.addEventListener('DOMAttrModified', handler);
    var attr = 'TEST';
    document.body.setAttribute(attr, 'foo'); // aka $('body').attr(attr, 'foo');
    document.removeEventListener('DOMAttrModified', handler);
    document.body.setAttribute(attr, null);
    return supported;
  }
```