# Can you have a JavaScript hook trigger after a DOM element's style object changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-events

An element has a JavaScript `style` object which contains the different names and values of CSS styles. I'd like to trigger a function every time this object changes **without use of polling**. Is there any way to do this in a way that is cross-browser compatible and would work reliably with third party code (because let's say you're providing a drop-in script)? Binding a JavaScript event like `DOMAttrModified` or `DOMSubtreeModified` won't suffice because they don't work in Chrome.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561845/firing-event-on-dom-attribute-change

Comment: I have an answer, but, are you targeting ancient browsers? or just major browsers?

Comment: @3p3r I am targeting older versions of browsers as well but I'd definitely be interested in a solution that only targets newer versions

Comment: @3p3r But no I don't care about old browsers that no one uses, like Konqueror or whatever...

Comment: @user730569 I've [already answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11011106/1055628), use `getter` and `setter` for maximum performance

Comment: why dont you use the change event of Jquery. and if you little workout more, you will find a live event of jquery which pretty much does what you need. Regards

Answer (score 56, accepted):

**Edit 4:** Live Demo

```js
$(function() {
  $('#toggleColor').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('darkblue');
  }).attrchange({
    trackValues: true,
    callback: function(event) {
      $(this).html("<ul><li><span>Attribute Name: </span>" + event.attributeName + "</li><li><span>Old Value: </span>" + event.oldValue + "</li><li><span>New Value: </span>" + event.newValue + "</li></ul>");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}
#toggleColor {
  height: 70px;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
  background-color: #DBEAF9;
}
#toggleColor span {
  font-weight: bold;
}
#toggleColor.darkblue {
  background-color: #1A9ADA;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://meetselva.github.io/attrchange/javascripts/attrchange.js"></script>
<p>Click below div to toggle class darkblue.</p>
<div id="toggleColor"></div>
```

**Edit 3:** I have put all this together as a plugin that can be downloaded from git [**attrchange**](https://github.com/meetselva/attrchange) and here is the [**demo page**](http://meetselva.github.com/attrchange/).

**Edit 2:**

1. Fix for propertName in IE7 & IE8

**Edit 1:**

1. Handle multiple elements
2. Ordered the conditions as MutationObserver, DOMAttrModified and onpropertychange for better implementation.
3. Added modified Attribute Name to the callback.

Thanks to @benvie for his feedback.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/zFVyv/10/ (Tested in FF 12, Chrome 19 and IE 7.)

```
$(function() {
    (function($) {
        var MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver || window.MozMutationObserver;

        function isDOMAttrModifiedSupported() {
            var p = document.createElement('p');
            var flag = false;

            if (p.addEventListener) p.addEventListener('DOMAttrModified', function() {
                flag = true
            }, false);
            else if (p.attachEvent) p.attachEvent('onDOMAttrModified', function() {
                flag = true
            });
            else return false;

            p.setAttribute('id', 'target');

            return flag;
        }

        $.fn.attrchange = function(callback) {
            if (MutationObserver) {
                var options = {
                    subtree: false,
                    attributes: true
                };

                var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
                    mutations.forEach(function(e) {
                        callback.call(e.target, e.attributeName);
                    });
                });

                return this.each(function() {
                    observer.observe(this, options);
                });

            } else if (isDOMAttrModifiedSupported()) {
                return this.on('DOMAttrModified', function(e) {
                    callback.call(this, e.attrName);
                });
            } else if ('onpropertychange' in document.body) {
                return this.on('propertychange', function(e) {
                    callback.call(this, window.event.propertyName);
                });
            }
        }
    })(jQuery);

    $('.test').attrchange(function(attrName) {
        alert('Attribute: ' + attrName + ' modified ');
    }).css('height', 100);

});
```

**Ref:**

1. [Detect if DOMAttrModified supported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4562426/297641)
2. [DOMAttrModified for chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10466236/297641)
3. [Mutation Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOM_Mutation_Observers)
4. [Why should we avoid using Mutation events?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Mutation_events)
5. [onPropertyChange IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536956%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> Mutation Observers is the proposed replacement for mutation events in DOM4. They are expected to be included in Firefox 14 and Chrome 18

**Browser Support:**

`onpropertychange` - is supported in IE (tested in IE 7)

`DOMAttrModified`  - is supported in IE 9, FF and Opera

`MutationObservers`   - is very new and it worked fine in [Chrome 18](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/05/dom-mutationobserver-reacting-to-dom-changes-without-killing-browser-performance/). Not sure how far it is supported and yet to be tested in Safari.

Thanks [@benvie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10868104/can-you-have-a-javascript-hook-trigger-after-a-dom-elements-style-object-change/11004907#comment14381951_11004907) on adding info about WebkitMutationObserver

Comment: Thanks! What is browser support like for `WebkitMutationObservers`? (How  far back in chrome and safari does it go?) What about `onPropertyChange`?

Comment: MutationObservers are very new but are supported in very recent WebKit and Firefox. They are the future of DOM modification events though, and I'm happy to see them included in this answer. ++ this answer

Comment: Oh except it'd be better if it handled the unprefixed version as well (which Firefox 15 supports). `var MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver || window.MozMutationObserver`.

Comment: @benvie Where could I find the specific browser versions that support them?

Comment: Chrome 18, Firefox 13?, References: http://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/05/dom-mutationobserver-reacting-to-dom-changes-without-killing-browser-performance/ https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=749920  http://lists.webkit.org/pipermail/webkit-dev/2012-June/021039.html (it's worth noting that MutationObservers have 5-10x better performance than the Mutation Events they replace which is why vendors are so eager to get them out in the wild)

Comment: @benvie Thanks for the pointers and the reference links. Updated the post.

Comment: I came up with a derivative of this that it's a bit more performant and includes property name as well (style changes are just named 'style' except with onpropertychange) https://gist.github.com/2920623

Comment: @benvie definitely a lot of improvements and also included some nice features.. let me try it out here and will update.. Thank you.

Comment: @user730569 It seems it is available since IE 5. >> http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/tagpages/attributes/onpropertychange.htm <<

Comment: @Vega: do these events get triggered when an element style is altered by non-programmatic means? e.g. a new stylesheet is loaded that affects rendering of a particular element

Comment: There's no need for the `attachEvent` branch in `isDOMAttrModifiedSupported`: DOM mutation event support coincides with `addEventListener` support in IE (both were introduced in IE 9).

Comment: @o.v I don't think so.. >> http://jsfiddle.net/skram/zFVyv/8/ << The style sheet is loaded later after the listeners.

Comment: @Vega: curious. I imagine that implies DOM mutation events don't necessarily reflect rendering mutations (probably for a good performance reason too) - worth mentioning in your answer imo

Comment: This looks good, I've been using this plugin called CSS Tie, which still works well with the latest jQuery version (1.7). Check it out for inspiration... https://github.com/revsystems/jQuery-Tie

Comment: @Vega: This is close to what I'm looking for, except that (for example) I also need to be notified when an element's width changes due to things like the window being resized (think about a block-level element whose width is set to '80%' and we're trying to monitor its width). Can you think of a way to extend this plugin's capabilities to do that?  I realize that we could handle those changes separately, like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6513415/718325), but I was hoping to get all of this functionality from one plugin. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT2:**

If you still want to use `mutation observer`, use this library: [mutation-summary](http://code.google.com/p/mutation-summary/)

---

**EDIT:**

As I said in my answer below and thanks to Vega for his comment, using things such as `object.watch` or `mutation observers` are not recommended for using in large apps. this is actual quote from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch):

> Generally you should avoid using `watch()` and `unwatch()` when
>   possible. These two methods are implemented only in Gecko, and they're
>   intended primarily for debugging use. In addition, **using watchpoints**
>   has a serious negative impact on performance, which is especially true
>   when used on **global objects**, such as window. You can usually use
>   ***setters*** and ***getters*** or ***proxies*** instead. See Compatibility for details.
>
> ### Warning

So if cross-browser compatibility is in your check list, Again, I highly suggest overriding `setter`s and `getter`s of `style` object.

---

use [`object.watch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch) and have these in mind for a cross-browser solution:

- [Javascript Object.Watch for all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029241/javascript-object-watch-for-all-browsers)
- [object.watch polyfill](https://gist.github.com/384583)
- [Watch for object properties changes in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269633/watch-for-object-properties-changes-in-javascript)

You may override `getter` and `setter` methods of element's `style` object too.

There is a jQuery plugin available for this, [jQuery watch](http://darcyclarke.me/dev/watch/)

Comment: I think watch uses polling.. and OP is looking for _object changes without use of polling_

Comment: @Vega Well, I don't know about the source code of Gecko that much, but I think by 'polling' OP meant manual `setInterval`s, didn't?

Answer (score 1):

I have found this little plugin that does exactly that and it can be changed to add any mutation you wish... Even scrollHeight change listener.

The plugin: http://www.jqui.net/jquery-projects/jquery-mutate-official/

here is the demo:
http://www.jqui.net/demo/mutate/

Comment: This plugin uses an interesting approach, but it does use polling (see the `setTimeout(reset, mutate.speed);` line (you may need to un-minify it to make it readable).

Answer (score 0):

Even for all of the most modern  browers there is no cross-browser way to achieve this. You would have to route all of your css style changes through a function which could trigger event listeners. This would be the cleanest method.

Answer (score 0):

In an answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2157963/1081234), it was suggested that if you know that style-setting interactions would be performed via a standard interface (i.e. *always* using jQuery etc.) it was suggested that custom events be fired whenever the library method is called.

This would allow for a broader support matrix but would leave any property change ignored if performed without using the library method. It also appears that such an approach is not applicable to [native setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters) as they cannot always be relied on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [attrchange jQuery plugin](http://meetselva.github.io/attrchange/). The main function of the plugin is to bind a listener function on attribute change of HTML elements.

Comment: That is what Vega's answer says (http://stackoverflow.com/a/11004907/971299) in fact the plugin was written BECAUSE OF this question!