# Watching for DOM changes, the elegant way

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I need to watch for an attribute change on any of the children of a specific DOM element. So far, I have been using [mutation events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Mutation_events).

The problem was - they were buggy: e.g. under Chromium, `DOMAttrModified` was not fired but `DOMSubtreeModified` was. The problem was easy to solve: because according to the specification, `DOMSubtreeModified` is fired if any of the other events is fired,  so I just listened to `DOMSubtreeModified`.

Anyway, Chromium, in the recent versions, stopped firing anything if an attribute has been modified.

The new [Mutation Observer API](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/02/Detect-DOM-changes-with-Mutation-Observers), however, works flawlessly.

Until now, I only need to fire a callback upon ANY change of the subtree of a specific element - simply because nothing else is supposed to change - so I solved my problem by just using mutation events & mutation observer (when available) in the same piece of code.

However, now I need to do more powerful filtering of the events (e.g. on new node, on removed node) - so is there **a library, possibly a jQuery plug-in**, that would allow me to elegantly use **both** of these APIs - `MutationObserver` if available and mutation events as a fallback, with the ability to filter for specific event types (e.g. element added, attribute changed).

E.g.

```
$("#test").watch({onNewElement: 1}, function(newElement){})
$("#test").watch({onNewAttribute: 1}, function(modifiedElement) {})
```

Or without jQuery

```
watchChanges("#test", {onNewElement: 1}, function(newElement){})
watchChanges("#test", {onNewAttribute: 1}, function(modifiedElement){})
```

Comment: Some searching found this, but it only supports the new API: http://code.google.com/p/mutation-summary/. I also found this, which appears to be a simple version of what you're asking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10868104/can-you-have-a-javascript-hook-trigger-after-a-dom-elements-style-object-change

Comment: I also found mutation-summary, but it does not support mutation events as a fallback.

The first answer of the thread you posted is basically what I do in my code to observe attribute changes.

In the same principle, a library can be built that allows watching for specific DOM events using both mutation observers and (as a fallback) events. That is what I need.

Comment: +1: I really dig 'best practice' questions.

Answer (score 2):

Would this work?

http://darcyclarke.me/development/detect-attribute-changes-with-jquery/

```
$.fn.watch = function(props, callback, timeout){
    if(!timeout)
        timeout = 10;
    return this.each(function(){
        var el      = $(this),
            func    = function(){ __check.call(this, el) },
            data    = { props:  props.split(","),
                        func:   callback,
                        vals:   [] };
        $.each(data.props, function(i) { data.vals[i] = el.css(data.props[i]); });
        el.data(data);
        if (typeof (this.onpropertychange) == "object"){
            el.bind("propertychange", callback);
        } else if ($.browser.mozilla){
            el.bind("DOMAttrModified", callback);
        } else {
            setInterval(func, timeout);
        }
    });
    function __check(el) {
        var data    = el.data(),
            changed = false,
            temp    = "";
        for(var i=0;i < data.props.length; i++) {
            temp = el.css(data.props[i]);
            if(data.vals[i] != temp){
                data.vals[i] = temp;
                changed = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(changed && data.func) {
            data.func.call(el, data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I saw it, but it's only for attributes. Plus, it falls back to setInterval even if the browser might support DOMAttrModified.

Comment: @Ivo right. Here is a thought though - are you in control of all these changes happening to the dom? Have you considered overriding the jquery manipulation methods to trigger a change/append/remove event (but that's assuming all the changes happen through jquery). I know that's a lot of work, and not exactly what you are looking for, but gets the work done.

Comment: I already got the work done a long time ago - I use both mutation events and observers to monitor attributes, and I use only the events to watch for newly-added stuff on the DOM - and I am not quite in control since I am watching for changes made via contenteditable/WYSIHTML5 editor. But it all works for the browsers I have planned to support.

This is more of a "best approach" question.
And monkey-patching jQuery seems like a bad idea. Monkey-patching the DOM API might be more appropriate but I'm still not sure.

Answer (score 2):

For efficient DOM monitoring with jQuery, you might take a look at the [jQuery Behavior Plugin](https://github.com/fschaefer/jquery-behavior) (Disclaimer: I'm the author) which utilizes a optimized version of [Live Query](https://github.com/brandonaaron/livequery). I'm using it in several products for 3 year now, without any problems.

Edit: Listening for attribute changes would work like this:

```
$.behavior({
    'div:first': {
        'changeAttr': function (event, data) {
            console.log('Attribute "' +  data.attribute + '" changed from "' + data.from + '" to "' + data.to + '"');
        }
    }
});

$('div:first').attr('foo', 'bar');
```