# Update the margin of a div in relation to the height of a div that dynamically changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, height

I'm wondering if this is possible with jQuery or JS.

I have a margin set on a div that is set by getting the height of a container that contains images.

```
var articleImageHeight = $('.slides_control').height();
$('.individual-article-contents').css('margin-top', articleImageHeight);
```

However, the container's images are essentially a slider, so the height of this container can change.

I'm wondering if it's possible to update the `articleImageHeight` variable live as the height of the container changes?

I am using [slidesJS](http://www.slidesjs.com/) for the slider in the container.

Here's an example of what I'm working on: http://goo.gl/FdftC

Many thanks,
R

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/zFVyv/10/](http://jsfiddle.net/zFVyv/10/) -- [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10868104/can-you-have-a-javascript-hook-trigger-after-a-dom-elements-style-object-change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10868104/can-you-have-a-javascript-hook-trigger-after-a-dom-elements-style-object-change) - shoudl get you going in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would probably do for this is to add your snippet of script as a function and then to call that function every time the slide changes. This will mean you need to make a slight modification to the plugin. Having a look at the plug the main animate function is simply called `animate()`.

So as a quick example

```
updateHeight = function(){
   articleImageHeight = $('.slides_control').height();
   $('.individual-article-contents').css('margin-top', articleImageHeight);
}
```

The above adds your bit to a function and then add `updateHeight();` to line 236... if you're using the un-minified version of the plugin.

Just above the line that says `} // end animate function`

.. just a thought a what might look a bit nicer is to use `.animate` rather than `.css` for updating the top margin... but hey I don't know what you're working on so is entirely up to you.

**----EDIT----**
Just an update... we found an animateComplete() callback on the plugin which worked a charm.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I'm struggling to get this to work. I've managed to wrap it all in a updateHeight function, but moving the updateHeight(); to slides.js stops it from working. Maybe we could chat quickly?

Comment: Ok sure, I haven't tried this out so I'll download the plugin and set up a test too.

Comment: This might be a stupid question but how do we go into a chat :) ... I've never been into one before.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try and see if it allows us to chat. You can have a look at what I'm working on via the link I shared in the question.

Comment: You have to make a lot of comments ;)

Comment: hahaha ok .... just looking at the plugin site .. there is actually a oncomplete option

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24648/discussion-between-rdck-and-vletech)