# How to know when a class changed/added to an HTML element?

Tags: javascript, dom, jquery

I have a list that looks like this:

```
<ul id="colors">
 <li class="variant on">red</li>
 <li class="variant off">blue</li>
 <li class="variant off">white</li>
 <li class="variant off">black</li>
</ul>
```

I want get an event when an item changes from off to on class changes, e.g. if the following happens:

```
 <li class="variant off">red</li>
 <li class="variant on">blue</li>
```

For that I tried to use livequery but I don't manage to get the events or set it right.

```
$('#colors li.on').livequery(function(){ 
                             console.log(this.text())
                          });
```

Comment: livequery is not a jquery function. live() is not included in jquery 2.0.0

Comment: livequery is the only plugin I found that claims can do it

Comment: This is a fairly clean way to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950038/jquery-fire-event-if-css-class-changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would only be possible in modern browsers that supports the [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/MutationObserver) object. You will not be able to observe DOM changes directly otherwise. You could always write some interceptors of the `addClass` function that would automatically raise events, but I would not recommend this. What you are trying to achieve is pretty bad design. **You should not rely on the DOM to keep track of your application state**.

Comment: did you ever use livequery plugin?

Comment: @GuyKorland, no I never did, but I quickly took a look and that's not what it does. Basically it does the same thing as passing a second selector to the `on` function in jQuery.

Comment: I found this answer, which seems to provide solution for browsers which don't support MutationObserver http://stackoverflow.com/a/11004907/593425

Comment: @GuyKorland, Just don't do this... listening to DOM changes to track your application state is ugly and inefficient... *Unless you would be writing a two-way binding feature*

Comment: I don't see any other option, the classes are changed by third part scripts which I have no control of, but I do need to react on class change.

Comment: @Guy Korland worst case can add a `setInterval` for browsers that don't support DOM observation events and run a function that checks the class constantly

Comment: @GuyKorland, wich third-party scripts? Did you read their docs to see if they generate events in such situations? Are the third-party scripts using jQuery? If they are you could try the implementation that Joseph proposed. Otherwise you could check if you can use a similar approach to intercept actions performed by the third-party's scripts. In last resort, without the `MutationObserver`, you could regularly check the DOM for changes using `setInterval` or `setTimeout`. If you know what user actions triggers those changes, you could also listen to the same events the other script listen's to.

Answer (score 1):

An ugly way to do it is to patch the jQuery functions with some intermediate functions of yours before running jQuery's implementation. You could run intermediate code on `addClass` and `removeClass`.

For example, patching the `addClass`. We take the original `addClass`

```
jQuery.fn.addClass = (function(){
  var addClass = jQuery.fn.addClass;
  return function(){
    //do stuff here before running the original addClass
    //you could collect callbacks and run them here
    return addClass.apply(this,arguments);
  }
}());
```

The other way would be [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/MutationObserver?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/DOM_Mutation_Observers) which currently is only supported by Chrome, Firefox and Safari.